# Optiplex 760 recognizes PCI-Express card as SDVO

Tags: network-adapter, pci-express, dell-optiplex

I plugged a hp nc364t network card into the PCI-Express slot of my Optiplex 760. The NIC is fully working I tested it in another PC. However the Optiplex just recognizes the NIC as a SDVO card according to the BIOS. If I plug an Ethernet cable into a port of the NIC nothing happens... The Lights which normally indicate that a port is used are not lightning up. Any help is appreciated. I already removed the BIOS battery. My BIOS Version is A16.

Comment: Is there another pci slot you can try?

Comment: No there is only one PCI-E slot. The other one is a PCI...